# events.js:377 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event / req.login is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have been in the process of building a server using node.js, express.js, Mongoose, and MongoDB. After trying to implement passport and JWT authentication, I have encountered an error (seen in the link) every time I try to make a request to my '/login' endpoint. This error occurs when I make a request through Postman using a username and password from my database to test if the user is assigned a JWT token.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6e4Z.png

All of my endpoints, except for the one in my auth.js file, work fine in my index.js file, which is the main file where everything gets imported. I do not have any problems getting/staying connected to my database, so this leads me to believe that the issue stems from some mistake in the error handling.

This is how the middleware is set up in the index.js file, right above my endpoints.

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Models = require('./models');

const Movies = Models.Movie;
const Genres = Models.Genre;
const Directors = Models.Director;
const Users = Models.User;

function displayErrorMsg(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(`Error: ${err}`);
}

function resJSON(model, res) {
  return model.find().then(data => res.json(data));
}

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/filmfeverDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(res => console.log('DB Connected!'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err, err.message));

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(express.static(`public`));
  app.use(morgan('common'));


let auth = require('./auth')(app);
const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport"),
  LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy,
  Models = require("./models.js"),
  passportJWT = require("passport-jwt"),
  config = require('./configs').config

let Users = Models.User,
  JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy,
  ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "Username",
      passwordField: "Password"
    },
    (username, password, callback) => {
      console.log(username + "  " + password);
      Users.findOne({ Username: username }, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return callback(error);
        }
        if (!user) {
          console.log("incorrect username");
          return callback(null, false, {
            message: "Incorrect username."
          });
        }
        console.log("finished");
        return callback(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);

passport.use(
  new JWTStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: config.passport.secret
    },
    (jwtPayload, callback) => {
      return Users.findById(jwtPayload._id)
        .then(user => {
          return callback(null, user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return callback(error);
        });
    }
  )
);
```

auth.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken"),
  passport = require("passport");

require("./passport"); 

let generateJWTToken = user => {
  return jwt.sign(user, config.passport.secret, {
    subject: user.Username,
    expiresIn: config.passport.expiresIn,
    algorithm: "HS256"
  });
};

/* POST login. */
module.exports = router => {
  router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", { session: false }, (error, user, info) => {
      if (error || !user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "something is not right",
          user: user
        });
      }
      req.login(user, { session: false }, error => {
        if (error) {
          res.send(error);
        }
        let token = generateJWTToken(user.toJSON());
        return res.json({ user, token });
      });
    })(req, res);
  });
};
```

Here is my Mongoose connection and my imports of the auth.js, passport.js, and passport module files located in my index.js file.

```
mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/filmfeverDB', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(res => console.log('DB Connected!'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err, err.message));

let auth = require('./auth')(app);
const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');
```

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034257/typeerror-req-login-is-not-a-function-passport-js      How are you loading the middleware  (likely shown in the  index.js)?   Can you share you `indes.js`?

Comment: I added that block to the top of the post. Perhaps it has something to do with the placement of `app.use()`?

Comment: As it turns out, I had to move the middleware around and add `app.use(passport.initialize())` to the top. Thanks 